# Horizontal list with evenly spaced and centered text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to code homepage of responsive website to have three text boxes arranged horizontally as in the attached image. Text should be evenly spaced and centered across entire width of website.

I've been trying with `ul` and the `display: inline` command. I think this should be easy but I've been trying for hours and can't work it out. Here is the HTML:

```html
<ul id="promolist">
<li>NEW! GO IN STORE</li>
<li>0% FINANCE APPLY ONLINE</li>
<li>FREE DELIVERY ON ORDERS OVER &pound;50</li>
</ul>
```

Would really appreciate it if somebody could help me with the CSS. Cheers.

[Image showing expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8Gwu.jpg)

Comment: Look into `display:table`/`display:table-cell` layout for older browsers, flexbox for newer. Both should achieve the result you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks very much Jesse. Will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `justify-content: space-around` with the CSS3 flexible box layout. This exactly does what you need, evenly spaces out the list items with margins on either extreme ends.

```css
#promolist {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="promolist">
  <li>NEW! GO IN STORE</li>
  <li>0% FINANCE APPLY ONLINE</li>
  <li>FREE DELIVERY ON ORDERS OVER &pound;50</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll add in the `display: table`, `display: table-cell` example since flexbox is well covered. A bit of a dated technique, but has the advantage of compatibility down to IE8 (if that's your thing):

```css
#promolist {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed; /*force equal column width */
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#promolist li {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
 
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
 
  border-left: solid 1px #000;
}

#promolist li:first-child {
  border-left: none;  
}
```

```html
<ul id="promolist">
  <li>NEW! GO IN STORE</li>
  <li>0% FINANCE APPLY ONLINE</li>
  <li>FREE DELIVERY ON ORDERS OVER &pound;50</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to also target the `<li>` elements. Check out this jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/2L99k5ko/2/

Here is the code:

HTML:

```css
ul#promolist li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="promolist">
    <li>NEW! GO IN STORE</li>
    <span>|</span>
    <li>0% FINANCE APPLY ONLINE</li>
    <span>|</span>
    <li>FREE DELIVERY ON ORDERS OVER &pound;50</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

With flexbox:

```css
#promolist {
  display: flex; /* Magic begins */
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#promolist > li {
  flex: 1; /* Equal widths, covering all the container */
  text-align: center; /* Center inner text horizontally */
}
```

```html
<ul id="promolist">
  <li>NEW! GO IN STORE</li>
  <li>0% FINANCE APPLY ONLINE</li>
  <li>FREE DELIVERY ON ORDERS OVER &pound;50</li>
</ul>
```